# Flutter voice sdk support for both ios and Android

Tags: flutter, voice, agora.io

Is there any voice SDK available for a flutter.
I want to add voice calling feature in my app, So far I have integrated agora video SDK bt I want specific voice SDK which supports both platform i.e ios and android

Answer (score 0):

Agora audio sdk for flutter is still under testing phase right now, if you want to use it for your flutter app you can find the SDK over here : https://github.com/AgoraIO/Flutter-SDK/tree/audio-only